# symmetrical encryption encrypting lots of small blocks

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

I'm trying to use the .Net symmetrical encryption System.Security.Cryptography to encrypt many small blocks of text without adding too much storage overhead (processing time is not important, just size). The obvious way would be to just jam them all together and encrypt the result as a single big block but that won't work in my case.

The background is that I am developing a tool that someone can use to send me a .docx word document so that I can troubleshoot problems in the structure without knowing the contents. I intend to do this by symmetrically encrypting each `<w:t>` element (which could be anything from a part of a word to a whole paragraph)

I want to be able to move and/or delete such text elements and the user to still be able to decrypt the document when I give it back, so it seems to me I have no choice but to encrypt each element separately, but with AES if you have thousands of blocks of a few bytes each, the storage overhead is huge.

Comment: Are you sure that, even if in chunks, you won't get from the user the whole .docx?

Comment: What do you mean by "problems in the structure"? I still can't tell from what you have put down here what you are trying to achieve maybe an example would help ?

Comment: OK say the user has a problem with bulleted list formatting or style definitions or maybe some kind of corruption. Say I'm an expert at that kind of thing and I could look at the document and fix it, but he doesn't want me to know the contents of the document. If it's a corruption I might need to delete a couple of paragraphs.

Comment: If the document is corrupted then Word will inform the user. If it's a problem with a bulleted list or formatting then how does the user know that it is a problem? I think there is still something missing here are you already modifying the contents of this word document and are trying to error check your mods ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best encryption for any information that you don't want to be read is for the information not being there in the first place.

If you only care about the structure of the document why don't you let it out completely of the transfer and replace it with place holders?

- On the client side create a data store with all the removed content associated to a place holder (example: {1}, {2}, {3} ... etc)
- Send yourself the structure and the place holders (i.e. that `<w:t>{1}</w:t>`)
- Fix the structure.
- Return the fixed structure to the client side and on the client side put back the document together by replacing the place holders with the original content.

That way you don't transmit any sensible information (it remains on the client side and no information CAN be compromised except for the structure of the document itself). In addition you'll be getting a smaller file size transferred since most of the content won't be there.

Even better you can let the client see the file before sending it to you so that he can verify that all the sensible information has, in fact, been removed.

Comment: Thanks I've done a bit more thinking and also taken into account the last paragraph of Daniel's response below. I think a modification of your technique will give the best compromise in my situation - I can store the mapping from placeholder -> original textin a "hidden" "blob" inside the word document, encrypted as a single block. That way the user only needs a password to reconstruct the original document and doesn't need to remember where he saved the placeholder map file. This would be a useful design in other situations where you have a large number of small plaintexts.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy solution here, and basically you are asking us to design your whole application. You could use CTR mode encryption, which is a streaming mode for block ciphers. With streaming mode you only require as many encrypted bytes as plain text bytes.

That said, with streaming mode you still need to store some kind of nonce. This nonce must be present to secure the ciphertext. Sometimes the nonce can however be calculated from context; e.g. a hash over the file name should do the trick. This may be harder for the elements within the document though.

Note that you will have to invent a scheme to convert the data into bytes and back (determine the alphabet, and encode the alphabet). If this scheme is not efficient you may end up with a huge overhead.

Answer (score 0):

AES having a block size of 128 bit causes an overhead of 8 byte per encrypted fragment in average - not to bad in my opinion. You could concatenate all fragments, encrypt them as one large block and finally split it and put all fragments in place again. This will work until you start moving around and deleting fragments unless you come up with some countermeasure.

You could for example prefix every encrypted fragment with the position in the concatenate block and use a stream cipher like RC4 instead of AES - this allows you to bring the encrypted fragments back into their original order filling gaps from deleted elements with arbitrary padding values and decrypt it correctly.

This might bring the overhead a bit down but you probably still need four bytes. You will probably also have to encode the cipher texts as hexadecimal or Base64 strings because you don't want raw binary data in your XML. But this encoding will yield a much larger overhead than some padding from using AES and therefore you may as well just go with the simplest solution.

Final thought - when you use a block cipher like AES you have to be careful when encrypting several fragments with the same key because equal plaintexts may yield equal cipher texts. See [block cipher modes of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) for details.

Answer (score 0):

To encrypt something with the minimal overhead I would suggest a stream cypher, such as Rabbit, or alternatively a block cypher, such as AES in CTR mode.  Both avoid the requirement for padding.  You will need to think very carefully about what your encryption keys are going to be.  There are ways to derive many sub-keys from a single secret master key and some less secure ancillary data.  Look up Key Derivation Functions (KDFs).  Examples are [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) and [HKDF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869).